# Setting NSDate from NSString not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c

`myObject.theEnd` and `myObject.theStart` are strings and it has the date format of `Thu Feb 31` like wise...

```
NSDateFormatter *format=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [format setDateFormat:@"EEE MMM dd"]; 
        NSDate *end = [format dateFromString:myObject.theEnd];
        NSDate *start = [format dateFromString:myObject.theStart];
        NSDate *current = [NSDate date];
```

When `theEnd` is `Thu Feb 31`, `NSDate *end` shows as `1970-5-19 14:30 +0000`. It is the same with `NSDate *start` and `NSDate *current`.

Why is this ? and How can i solve this ?

Comment: how you want to set ur date? i thnk your formator is not correct.

Comment: Well, i need to convert the string which is in the format `Wed Mar 13` to a `NSDate`

Answer (score 6):

I bet `theEnd` is not showing as `1970-05-19 14:30 +0000`. I bet it's showing as `(null)` since there is never a 31st February! e.g. I get:

```
NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[format setDateFormat:@"EEE MMM dd"]; 
NSDate *end = [format dateFromString:@"Thu Feb 31"];
NSLog(@"end = %@", end);
```

=>

```
2012-05-20 16:38:31.620 test-date[42307:707] end = (null)
```

Also I bet that you are in a timezone that is 9.5 hours east of UTC. And `1970-05-19 14:30 +0000` is actually what you will then get when you parse today's date of `Sun May 20`. For instance I am currently in BST so UTC+0100 and I get:

```
NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[format setDateFormat:@"EEE MMM dd"]; 
NSDate *start = [format dateFromString:@"Sun May 20"];
NSLog(@"start = %@", start);
```

=>

```
2012-05-20 16:38:31.621 test-date[42307:707] start = 1970-05-19 23:00:00 +0000
```

Since it's parsing to `1970-05-20 00:00:00` (there's no year so that component is "`0`" = `1970`) in the current timezone, which is `1970-05-19 23:00:00 +0000` in UTC.

If you want to get around that problem, then set the timezone of the formatter to UTC:

```
[format setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
```

To get the year into the current year you could do something like this:

```
NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[format setDateFormat:@"EEE MMM dd"];
[format setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];

NSDate *start = [format dateFromString:@"Sun May 20"];
NSLog(@"start = %@", start);

NSDate *today = [NSDate date];

NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *todayComponents = [gregorian components:NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:today];
NSDateComponents *startComponents = [gregorian components:(NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit) fromDate:start];

[startComponents setYear:[todayComponents year]];
[startComponents setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];

start = [gregorian dateFromComponents:startComponents];

NSLog(@"start = %@", start);
```

It's not that pretty, but it works. Alternatively you could just append the current year to the string you pass into the formatter and add `yyyy` to the formatter style:

```
NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[format setDateFormat:@"EEE MMM dd yyyy"];
[format setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];

NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *todayComponents = [gregorian components:NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:today];

NSString *dateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Sun May 20 %i", [todayComponents year]];

NSDate *start = [format dateFromString:dateString];
NSLog(@"start = %@", start);
```

Comment: Well, i have a String which has the format `Sun Mar 13`, and i need to convert it to a `NSDate` object. How can i do it ?

Comment: What do you want that to parse to, though? `Sun Mar 13` is not very well defined (i.e. what year?). See my edit for how to make that parse to `1970-03-13 00:00:00 +0000`. Maybe that's OK for your purpose?

Comment: It is actually the Year that is causing the problem. The year will always be the current year `2012`, but i am passing is in the format `Sun May 20` (without the year). I need `NSDate *start` to have the year as `2012` instead of having `1970`

Comment: Then you're going to have to set the year date component. Take a look at NSDateComponents and grab the components from the resulting date, set the year to the current year and then create a new date object.

Comment: I still didn't understand how to do it. Could you show me an example if possible ?

Comment: @sharonHwk Done. Two examples for you :-).